# How to pass php value which is passed as a parameter through url and displaying it in html page to be passed to another php file

Tags: php, html

I have html file where am using php code to display a value which is passed in url for example:

My variable value which is passed through url is "WORKSHOP" and variable name is "eventName"

Which is called in php page using php like as follows:

```
 <form action="reg_event_validate.php" method="post" id="htmlform" name="htmlform">
    <table  height="80% style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 60px; background-color:#D9E2F1; border-radius: 5px;" width="650px" align="center">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="2">
    <?php
    // The value of the variable name is found
    echo "<h3>Event Registration : " . $_GET["name"] . "</h3>";
    ?> 
    </th>
```

Now i would like to pass that name(eg: WORKSHOP) value to reg_event_validation.php. How to go about. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the value once the above form is submitted or are you using the above form to display the previously submitted value? Also the form above is using POST and your using $_GET to retrieve the value, which could cause issues depending on my first question.

Answer (score 3):

Try to pass the value using a hidden input field like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenval" value="<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>"
```

and try to access this in form action page like

```
echo $_POST['hiddenval'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use input type hidden

```
<input type='hidden' name='eventName' value='<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>' />
```

**OR**, Append as `Query String`

```
action="reg_event_validate.php?eventName=<?php echo $_GET["name"]; ?>"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways. Add a hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="workshop" value="some_value" />
```

Or you can append to action in form

```
<form method="get" action="reg_event_validation.php?workshop=somevalue" name="form">
....
```